# Variable is not defined Javascript + Parse.com

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, parse-platform

I have a big problem. (Line: 40)

I want to create an input button by JS where attribute onclick is a function with one parameter. "onclick = goGrupa(gid)". This not working. "Uncaught ReferenceError: gid is not defined".

Next step is function goGrupa(id) - 1 parameter and I need only show him in console.log now.

What's the problem?

Javascript Code:

```
Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

$(document).ready(function(){
    WyszukajPrzedmioty();
});

function WyszukajPrzedmioty(){
   var zapPrzedmioty = new Parse.Query(new Parse.Object.extend("Przedmioty"));
   var output = "<ul>";
   zapPrzedmioty.include("grupy");

   zapPrzedmioty.equalTo("uczelnia",currentUser.get("nazwaUczelni"));
   zapPrzedmioty.equalTo("kierunek",currentUser.get("kierunek"));
   zapPrzedmioty.equalTo("rok",currentUser.get("rok"));
   zapPrzedmioty.find({
    success:function(przedmioty){
        for (var i in przedmioty){
            console.log(i+ " przedmiot: "+przedmioty[i]);
            var nazwaPrzedmiotu = przedmioty[i].get("nazwaPrzedmiotu");
            var kierunek = przedmioty[i].get("kierunek");
            var rok = przedmioty[i].get("rok");

            output += "<li><div id=\"naglowek\">";
      output += "<p><b style=\"font-size:20px; text-transform: uppercase;\">"+nazwaPrzedmiotu+"</b><br></p>";
      output += "<i>"+kierunek+"</i>, rok: <i>"+rok+"</i><br>";
      output += "</div>";

            var g = przedmioty[i].get("grupy");
            if (g.length > 0){
                output += "<br><b style=\"font-size: 20px;\"> Grupy: </b>";
                output += "<table>"
                console.log("Znaleziono grupy.");
                for (var j in g){
                    var dziekanska = g[j].get("dziekanska");
                    var gid = g[j].id;
                    if (g[j].get("lab") == 5){
                        var lab = "nie dotyczy";
                        output += "<tr><td class=\"left\">Dziekańska: "+dziekanska+"</td>";
                        output += "<td class=\"right\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Dołącz\" onclick=goGrupa(gid)></td></tr>";
                    }
                    else{
                        var lab = g[j].get("lab");
                        output += "<tr><td class=\"left\">Dziekańska: "+dziekanska+", lab: "+lab+"</td>";
  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM \/
                        output += "<td class=\"right\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Dołącz\" onclick=goGrupa(gid)></td></tr>";
                    }


                    console.log (j+" grupa: "+dziekanska+" "+lab+" id: "+gid);
                }
                output += "</table>";
            }
            else{
                console.log("Nie ma grup");
                output += "</li>";
            }
        }
        $("#listaPrzedmiotowStudent").html(output + "</ul>");
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
}
function goGrupa(gid){
  console.log(gid);
}
```

And screen:
[image: screen]

I try change this on:

> onclick=\"goGrupa("+gid+")\", onclick=\"goGrupa(gid)\",
>   onclick=goGrupa("+gid+"), onclick=goGrupa(gid)

and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting `"onclick=goGrupa(gid)"` to `"onclick=goGrupa(" + gid + ")"`

Comment: You beat me by 10 secs.

Comment: Error.. Uncaught ReferenceError: LopjBQjsxz is not defined
I try a lot of methods: 
onclick=goGrupa(" + gid + ")
onclick=\"goGrupa(gid)\"
onclick=\"goGrupa(" + gid + ")\"
And no working

Comment: @RafałJończyk: look at the generated code. It should be pretty clear why you get that error and what you need to do to fix that.

Comment: @FelixKling Can you tell me what is wrong? I searching errors 3 hours and can't find..

Comment: @RafałJończyk : `goGrupa(LopjBQjsxz)` passes the value of the *variable* `LopjBQjsxz` to the function. Of course that fails, since such a variable doesn't exist, similar to what you had earlier with `gid`. You want to pass a *string*: `goGroupa('LopjBQjsxz')`

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much. I forgot about this method. Bad day today :< Thank you one more time

Comment: @RafałJończyk You should really consider refactoring your code, it has a lot of code smells. Long method, variable names are not clear, too deep indentation. Split into smaller functions

Comment: @SlavaShp. Half a year interested in js and data storage in the cloud. We can say that this is my one of the first codes in this connection. Any advice is helpful for me :)

Comment: You should read the book 'Clean Code'. The things I mentioned and many more are explained there with examples and explained why they are needed